# implementing python multithreading into the calculation for a progressbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, progress-bar

i am trying to create a progressbar similar to [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm)'s. Everything works just fine, but i noticed that the calculation for every step of the progressbar  (for big iterables, len > 50) takes a lot of time. this is my code.

```py
def progressbar(iterable):
    def new(index):
        #... print the progressbar
    for i in range(len(iterable)):
        new(i)
        yield iterable[i]
```

the problem is that while on small iterables the time that `new()` takes to execute is indifferent, on larger iterables it becomes a problem (which does not occur in the tqdm library). For example the following code takes a few seconds to execute. It should be instant!

```py
iterator = progressbar(range(1000))
for i in iterator: pass
```

can you tell me a way to remedy this thing? maybe implementing multithreading?

Comment: On python3.8, your last snippet with a `range(100000)` takes 0.11 seconds to run. Have you run your code through a profiler?

Comment: what is making the whole thing slow is new function, that is calculating the percentage etc... i figured out that it takes 0.001 seconds to execute. On small iterables it is not a problem but when they become larger that 100 it is @imochoa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what the issue is (you are not showing all of your calculations), but I believe your approach can be improved with the way your progress bar is handling the `iterable` it is being passed:

1. First, you are assuming that the `iterable` is indexable, which may not always be the case.
2. If it is a generator function, then the length may not be determinable with the `len` function nor would converting the generator to a list to get its length be necessarily efficient and it would probably defeat the purpose of having a progress bar, as in the example below. Your interface should therefore allow the user to pass an optional `total` parameter (as `tqdm` does) to explicitly specify the length of the `iterable`.
3. You can do some upfront calculations outside of function `new` so that`new` can quickly calculate based on the value of the `index` argument how wide the bar should be.

I would suggest the following changes:

```
def progressbar(iterable, total=None):
    def new(index):
        #... print the progressbar
        from math import floor
        nonlocal division, width
        n_division = floor(index / division + .5)
        remainder = width - n_division
        print('|', '.' * n_division, ' ' * remainder, '|', sep='', end='\r')

    if total is None:
        iterable = list(iterable)
        # we must convert to a list
        total = len(iterable)
    it = iter(iterable)

    width = 60 # with of progress bar
    division = total / 60 # each division represents this many completions

    try:
        for i in range(total):
            # ensure next value exists before printing it:
            yield next(it)
            new(i)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    print()

def fun():
    import time
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(.03)
        yield i

iterator = progressbar(fun(), total=1000)
values = [i for i in iterator]
print(values[0], values[-1])
```

**Multithreading**

Incorporating multithreading as a way of speeding up processing is problematic. The following is a (naive) attempt to do so that fails because although multithreading is being used to get the values from the generator function `fun`, the generator function is still generating values only once every .03 seconds. It's should also be clear that if the `iterable` is, for example, a simple list that multithreading is not going to be able to iterate the list more quickly than using a single thread:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def progressbar(iterable, total=None):
    def new(index):
        #... print the progressbar
        from math import floor
        nonlocal division, width
        n_division = floor(index / division + .5)
        remainder = width - n_division
        print('|', '.' * n_division, ' ' * remainder, '|', sep='', end='\r')
    if total is None:
        iterable = list(iterable)
        # we must convert to a list
        total = len(iterable)
    it = iter(iterable)

    width = 60 # with of progress bar
    division = total / 60 # each division represents this many completions
    
    with ThreadPool(20) as pool:
        for i, result in enumerate(pool.imap(lambda x: x, iterable)):
            yield result
            new(i)
        print()

def fun():
    import time
    for i in range(1000):
        time.sleep(.03)
        yield i

iterator = progressbar(fun(), total=1000)
values = [i for i in iterator]
print(values[0], values[-1])
```

What would have sped up processing would have been if the generator function itself had used multithreading. But, of course, one has no control over how the `iterable` is being created:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def progressbar(iterable, total=None):
    def new(index):
        #... print the progressbar
        from math import floor
        nonlocal division, width
        n_division = floor(index / division + .5)
        remainder = width - n_division
        print('|', '.' * n_division, ' ' * remainder, '|', sep='', end='\r')

    if total is None:
        iterable = list(iterable)
        # we must convert to a list
        total = len(iterable)
    it = iter(iterable)

    width = 60 # with of progress bar
    division = total / 60 # each division represents this many completions

    try:
        for i in range(total):
            # ensure next value exists before printing it:
            yield next(it)
            new(i)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    print()


def fun():
    import time

    def fun2(i):
        time.sleep(.03)
        return i

    with ThreadPool(20) as pool:
        for i in pool.imap(fun2, range(1000)):
            yield i

iterator = progressbar(fun(), total=1000)
values = [i for i in iterator]
print(values[0], values[-1])
```

Comment: sounds interesting, obviously the thing is not that simple, i also added estimated time etc... but this is a really good staring point, thanks, i am gonna work a bit on it and then i'll tell you!

Comment: I am going to look into also adding multithreading.

Comment: this is definitely the answer i was looking for, thanks! i am gonna accept this answer and give your bounty as first as the system allows it!

Comment: the problem wasn't actually the one i thought, i created a function that could substitute "print()" (with some features added), but found out it was really slow. using print it works smootly. however i found really interesting the process of using "next()".